# Wrong value in Javascript function param

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm iterating over a list of object in c:foreach loop and creating a call to a javascript function that complete the length of my var an call server:

```
<c:forEach items="${clientList}" var="cli" varStatus="index">
...
<a href="javascript:goToClientDetail(${cli.client.PK})">                                
     <img src="<%=imagesPath%>search.gif"  width="14" height="14" border="0" align="absmiddle"/>
</a>
```

If I show ${cli.client.PK} in my .jsp I can see the correct value, but the problem is that the javascript function is getting a wrong value.

**My JS function:**

```
<script language="javascript">
function goToClientDetail(pk){
    alert(pk);
    var res = pk.toString();
    while(res.length < 12){
        res = '0'.concat(res);
    }
    document.getElementById('idlocalClient').value=res;
    document.getElementById('fClientDetail').submit();
}
```

`alert(pk)` shows different value that `${cli.client.PK}` in the .jsp

Any hint?

Comment: Did you rename the method from irDetalleCliente to goToClientDetail or is it two different methods?

Comment: how/where/when is `goToClientDetail` called? what does it show? what should it show? saying it's "different" is of no value to your question

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake translating names to English. The function is called correctly (goToClientDetail)

Comment: Have you tried putting single quotes around the `${cli.client.PK}` in the method call? JavaScript might try to use the value of the variable as a variable itself.

Comment: @AhmedBajra +1 for you. It works with scaped quotes (doubles in my case) but I don't know why it is working in my other .jsp (I have a similar .jsp to get serverLocals) without quotes... A little bit strange... If you want post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @canillas alright, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting single quotes around the `${cli.client.PK}` in the method call? JavaScript might try to use the value of the variable as a variable itself.